# RailwayJS and Mongoose with option --coffee

Tags: node.js, mongoose, railway.js

does somebody know why data will not be stored in mongodb in a railway-project using the --coffee option?

Creating a project the regular way (w/o --coffee option) data will be saved in mongodb. So when do the following:

```
railway init blog && cd blog
```

and after modifying the database.json to

```
{ "development":
  { "driver":   "mongoose"
  , "host":     "localhost"
  , "database": "blog_dev"
  }
}
```

everything works fine when I install all dependencies and start the server with

```
npm install -l
railway g scaffold post title content
railway s
```

So far. But when I create a project with --coffee option like:

```
railway init blog --coffee
```

and after modifying the database.yml (this is different in coffe-mode) to

```
development:
  driver:   "mongoose"
  host:     "localhost"
  database: "blog_dev"
```

and after installing all dependencies and start the server with

```
npm install -l
railway g scaffold post title content --coffee
railway s
```

data will only stored in memory.

any idea?

Comment: using the old database.json file extension (with JSON content of course) it seems to work. maybee its in issue of railway using the --coffee option that it creates a database.yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `database.json` instead of `database.yml`:

```
{
  "development": {
    "driver": "mongoose",
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "blahblahblah"
  },
  "test": {
    "driver": "memory"
  }
}
```